# Can I fadeIn() the following, if so, how does the syntax look?

Tags: jquery

So currently I'm editing a dynamic h2 on my site through jQuery. But I want it to fadeIn() and then display the message. This is my current code:

```
$("#score h2").html("You are not correct! Try again.");
```

The code simply edits my h2. But I wish my h2 to fadeIn() and then have the message displayed.

Comment: Something has to fade in though .. does the `h2` have a background or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide it first to fade it in

```
$("#score h2").html("You are not correct! Try again.").hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: I believe the `.hide` is unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#score h2").hide().fadeIn(1000, function() {
    $(this).html("You are not correct! Try again.");
});
```

or to add the text before fading in:

```
$("#score h2").hide()
              .html("You are not correct! Try again.")
              .fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: +1 for hiding before changing the html. Semantics are satisfied.